# Why is glossaries so eager to insert \null?

Tags: glossaries

`\printglossaries` and friends insert the content of files created by `makeglossary` (or `\null` if that does not exist), see `\@print@glossary` in `glossaries.sty`. `makeglossaries` initializes the respective files with `\\null\n` before it executes xindy or makeindex to make really, really sure that *something* is inserted at the place of `\printglossaries`. The documentation states that as well:

> While the external files are missing,
>   these commands will just do \null for each missing glossary to assist dic-
>   tionary style documents that just use \glsaddall without inserting any
>   text.

This is a problem in some situations where this `\null` changes the output to the worse (e.g., [glossaries: count the number of used abbreviations (i.e. those to be output by \printacronyms)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499296/glossaries-count-the-number-of-used-abbreviations-i-e-those-to-be-output-by#comment1330878_499327)).
Apparently I am not the only one noticing this caveat because someone worked around it by jumping through a few hoops: https://github.com/egraff/ult-base/blob/master/texmf-tds/tex/latex/ult-base/ult-printglossary.sty

Why does glossaries do that at all (I don't get the explanation in the manual)? Are there better workarounds?

Comment: If a document contains only a printglossary command it would be a problem if it wouldn't create a page. But instead of hardcoding the \null it would be better if there was some option e.g. forcepage or if the command could be redefined. Make a feature request.

Comment: Why would that be a problem? If there is nothing to print... then don't print anything? Report sent (but requires approval by Nicola). Will post a link/further updates as they become available.

Comment: if there are no pages some stuff can not be written to the aux-file as it needs a "shipout".